# How to create array of objects in c# instantiating a class that takes one parameter?

Tags: c#

For example i have the code below:

```
var Example = new [] 
{ 
    new ClassName1("String1"), 
    new ClassName1("String2"), 
    new ClassName1("String3")
} ;
```

For the above i can just manually hard-code as many classes and pass in the string, however would like to know how do i create a list, say 200 and automatically loop to get the string field populated from a spreadsheet, for example?

Sorry i am quite new to C# so apologies if i am missing anything obvious.

Comment: If you don't know the number of objects beforehand, use a `List<ClassName1>`, add as many instances as you wish (using a `for` loop or the like), and then (optionally) convert it to an array. See [List<T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1).

Comment: You would do the two steps separately if you need a loop. Step 1: initialize an array of your set size: `var Example = new ClassName1[200];`. Step 2: loop through array and set `Example[index] = new ClassName1("String");`

Comment: Start point: [Google: c# + query + Excel](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+query+excel). There are plenty of links including previously asked questions and answers in [so].

Comment: Is the question how to get the values from an Excel spreadsheet or is the question how to turn a list of strings into a list of `ClassName1` instances? The latter is `var example = new [] { "string1", "string2", "string3", "string4" }.Select(x => new ClassName1(x)).ToArray();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer working with Lists - one major benefit of lists is that you don't need to know the size of the list when you create it, vs working with an array. You can make a list of pretty much anything (object / classes, etc.)

I pretended that your "ClassName1" is an "Employee", and your parameters (arguments) are the persons name - which was loaded from an excel spreadsheet. You didn't provide much information on what it is you're looking to do, how you plan on using things, etc - so i'm going to assume you're just trying to load things into a collection?

### Part 1 - Define the custom class / object

I made a class and gave it some properties - First Name, Something Else, and added Date. When you pass the employee's first name as a parameter, it saves the name to the 'first name' property /string. I've also made it automatically record the added date (with time) - to illustrate how this works.

```
public class Employee
{
    public string FirstName;
    public string SomethingElse;
    public DateTime addedDate; 

    // This is my constructor that takes one paramater (argument) 
    public Employee(string theirFirstName)
    {
        // I'm now going to save that paramater (argument) to a property of this instance 
        FirstName = theirFirstName;

        // doing this for the illustration 
        addedDate = DateTime.Now; 
    }

    // I created this constructor just incase someone forgot to provide a name when they called the code... 
    public Employee()
    {
        FirstName = "Unknown"; 
        addedDate = DateTime.Now; 
    }

}
```

### Part 2 - Creating your list and adding things to it

Don't be thrown off by the "ListFromExcel" list - You're seeing me create a list (of strings) and immediately adding some fake names to the list for us to work with. In your code, you'd have a function that calls "ListfromExcel.Add(**[excel record/string]**)", then you'd loop through the entries in the function.

You can see that i made a list of the class "Employee" - I created this empty list without providing a length. I'll call the employees.Add(name) to add items to this list - then i'll use a foreach loop to print data from each 'employee' in the list of employees.. if this makes sense.

```
public class Example
 {

    // As an example, you'd load the values from excel into this list of strings (using a function) 
    public List<string> ListFromExcel = new List<string>()
    {
        "Bob", "Frank", "Henry",
        "Sally", "Julia"
    };

    // We can make a list (collection) of virtually anything. I've created a list of the employee object (class): 
    public List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();


    public void CreateListOfEmployees()
    {
        // looping through each entry (string) in the ListFromExcel list: 
        foreach(string nameFromExcel in ListFromExcel)
        {
            // This is where I'm instantiating a new class with one paramater 
            employees.Add(new Employee(nameFromExcel));
        }

        // Just to demonstrate - I will output each item to the console 
        foreach (Employee person in employees)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(person.FirstName + " was added on " + person.addedDate); 
        }
    }
}
```

Hopefully this helps you - Please provide more information on what you're ultimately trying to accomplish if not, i'm sure we can help!

Comment: great! Thanks very much for the detailed explanation

Answer (score 0):

This is how you create a Initialize a array with a loop. You may want to use a `List<T>` instead of a array, if you do not know the amount of elements ahead of time.

```
string[] classArray = new string[200];

for(int i = 0; i < classArray.Length; i++){
  classArray[i] = new string("String" + (i+1));
}
```

I used string instead of your custom class, as it has a similar Constructor and online Compilers support it.

Getting data from a Spreadsheet is another question altogether. But you will propably need `i` for that one too.